# Building a ol3 web application with dynamic content and user registration

Tags: postgis, geoserver, openlayers, database, wfs-t

**My set-up:**

Currently I’m using a PostGIS database, with a GeoServer service and displaying the data with OpenLayers 3.  I use WFS data to display the features in clusters and I’m able to edit them with WFS-T.  The PostGIS database is very large ~250.000 features but I load them with the WFSBBOXLoader strategy. With the ol3edit template from Boundless, this works very well.

**My question:**

What is the best way/set-up to allow only registered user to modify features with the ol3 WFS-T system, such that the user can register themselves?

Should I even use my current set-up or other API's?
I just need the direction/ideas I should go... :)

PS: I don't like drupal+extensions...

Answer (score 1):

I am thinking about the same questions at the moment. We are looking into securing a WFS-T for a government contract.

Depending on your setup you may send the request from your client to a custom service using [XACML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XACML) which checks the current user and then either rejects or forwards the AJAX call to Geoserver.

There is probably a lot of work involved to get this right. I am also afraid that XACML service may slow the whole process too much down.

Alternatively I am thinking about securing the WFS just by limiting the access control to y domain. In that case it should not be possible to do anything from an outside script. And you can use any means of access control to applications/scripts running on your domain.

Cheers,
Dennis

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered GeoNode? It's based on Django which is used for user/groups authentication and it is using the same stack you mentioned (Postgres/PostGIS Geoserver & Openlayers) http://geonode.org/